# How to get cursor coordinates relative to matrix scale in pyglet/opengl?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I am making a 2D game in pyglet and use both glTranslatef and glScalef:

```
def background_motion(dt):
    if stars.left:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(stars.speed, 0, 0)
        stars.translation[0] += stars.speed
    if stars.right:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(-stars.speed, 0, 0)
        stars.translation[0] -= stars.speed
    if stars.up:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(0, -stars.speed, 0)
        stars.translation[1] -= stars.speed
    if stars.down:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(0, stars.speed, 0)
        stars.translation[1] += stars.speed 
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(background_motion, 0.05)

@window.event
def on_mouse_scroll(x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
    if scroll_y > 0:
        stars.scale += 0.01

    elif scroll_y < 0:
        stars.scale -= 0.01
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    pyglet.gl.glScalef(stars.scale,stars.scale, 1, 1)

    stars.image.draw()
    for s in game.ships:
        s.draw()

    pyglet.gl.glPushMatrix()
    pyglet.gl.glLoadIdentity()

    #HUD Start
    overlay.draw(stars.image.x,stars.image.y,game.ships,stars.scale,stars.image.width)
    if game.pause:
        pause_text.draw()
    #HUD End

    pyglet.gl.glPopMatrix()
    stars.scale = 1
```

However I also need the cursor coordinates relative to the background. For the movement I simply added the translation onto the x y coordinates which works however only when I don't scale the matrix:

```
@window.event
def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
    if player.course_setting:
        player.projected_heading = (x - stars.translation[0],y -stars.translation[1])
```

How can I get the cursor coordinates accounting for scale?

Comment: First things first: You shouldn't be using the fixed function matrix stack in the first place. It's been deprecated for well over a decade.

Comment: Divide `player.projected_heading` by `stars.scale`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to *unproject* the pointer position. Projection happens as following:

```
p_eye = M · p
p_clip = P · p_eye
```

at this point the primitive is clipped, but we can ignore this for the moment. After clipping comes the homogenous divide, which brings the coordinates into NDC space, i.e. the viewport is treated as a cuboid of dimensions [-1,1]×[-1,1]×[0,1]

```
p_NDC = p_clip / p_clip.w
```

From there it's mapped into pixel dimensions. I'm going to omit this step here.

Unprojecting is doing these operations in reverse. There's a small trick in there, regarding the homogenous divide, though; this is kind of an "antisymmetric" (not the proper term for this, but it gets across the point) operation, and happens at the end, for each projection and unprojection. Unprojection hence is

```
p_NDC.w = 1
p_eye' = inv(P)·p_NDC
p' = inv(M)·p_eye'
p = p' / p'.w
```

All of this has been wrapped into unproject functions for your convenience by GLU (if you insist on using the fixed function matrix stack) or GLM – but not my *linmath.h*, though.

Comment: Okay I tried using opengls unproject function like this: `pyglet.gl.gluUnProject(x,y,0,pyglet.gl.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,pyglet.gl.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,pyglet.gl.glViewport,0,0,0)` But that gave me the error: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double instance instead of int` What am I doing wrong?'

Comment: @Rabbid76 Okay now I get this error `TypeError: this function takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` from this line `model_view = np.array(pyglet.gl.glGetDoublev(pyglet.gl.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX))`